# How to hide sidebar group labels while using multiple column layout Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, sidebar

I have sidebar enhancements installed. These group labels annoy me to no extent. Just to be clear, the marked area in the image below is what I want to hide.

[image: Link to image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to "Hide Open Files". Go to VIEW > SIDE BAR > Select HIDE OPEN FILES - This will remove that section from the Sidebar.